# How to calculate resolution time in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, reporting, analytics, aggregation

I have data in the following form:

```
TicketID    Status    Datetime
25          Open      2016-07-21 11:46:40
25          Open      2016-07-22 09:42:40
25          Closed    2016-07-22 09:46:40
25          Open      2016-07-23 08:42:40
25          Open      2016-07-24 08:46:40
25          Open      2016-07-24 09:26:40
25          Closed    2016-07-25 11:46:40
```

I want to calculate the following:

((2016-07-22 09:46:40 - 2016-07-21 11:46:40) + (2016-07-25 11:46:40 - 2016-07-23 08:42:40))/2.

Comment: I don't think your calculation is correct.  The first value is "0".

Comment: Are you trying to calculate per ticket the average time it takes to complete them? Where each ticket can be opened and closed multiple times under the same ID. As @GordonLinoff says, your calculation seems to be wrong (probably just a typo). I assume it should be: `(('2016-06-22 09:46:40' - '2016-06-21 11:46:40') + ('2016-07-25 11:46:40' - '2016-06-23 08:42:40')) / 2`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea:  For each "open" get the next "closed".  Then only choose the "closed" values and take the minimum open to determine the length of time.  So, the following gets the pairs of times that you want:

```
select close_datetime, min(datetime) as open_datetime
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.DateTime
              from t t2
              where t2.status = 'Closed' and t2.DateTime > t.DateTime
             ) as close_datetime
      from t
      where status = 'Open'
     ) t
group by close_datetime;
```

You can then get the sum of the differences.  This gets the value in seconds:

```
select sum(timestampdiff(second, clsoe_datetime, open_datetime) as num_seconds
from (select close_datetime, min(datetime) as open_datetime
      from (select t.*,
                   (select t2.DateTime
                    from t t2
                    where t2.status = 'Closed' and t2.DateTime > t.DateTime
                   ) as close_datetime
            from t
            where status = 'Open'
           ) t
      group by close_datetime
     ) t
```

Comment: Check my answer too!

Answer (score 0):

This seems okay to me.

```
set @x=now(), @y=-1;

select 
    avg(timestampdiff(second,prev_stat_dt,curr_stat_dt))
from
    (select 
        TicketID,
            @y prev_stat,
            @y:=Status curr_stat,
            @x prev_stat_dt,
            @x:=DateTime curr_stat_dt
    from
        table1
    where
           Status in ('Open' , 'Closed')) t
where
    prev_stat = 'Open' and curr_stat = 'Closed';
```

Comment: The assignment of variables in separate expressions is not guaranteed to work.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`, so the four assignments could be in any order.

Comment: There's no way to do a lead/lag in MySQL? @GordonLinoff